# It is possible to undelete SObject and other metadata using api?

Tags: api, undelete

[image: salesforce deleted objects]

I know about [undelete()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_undelete.htm) from Enterprise API but it looks like only for records, anyway I tried it with request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
  <soapenv:Header>
     <urn:SessionHeader>
        <urn:sessionId>
00D28000001b4nTMwpuKlz
        </urn:sessionId>
     </urn:SessionHeader>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
     <urn:undelete>
        <urn:ids>01I28000001HT0s</urn:ids>
        <urn:ids>01I28000001aDre</urn:ids>
     </urn:undelete>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and response is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <LimitInfoHeader>
      <limitInfo>
        <current>3917</current>
        <limit>15000</limit>
        <type>API REQUESTS</type>
      </limitInfo>
    </LimitInfoHeader>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <undeleteResponse>
      <result>
        <errors>
          <message>Entity type is not undeletable</message>
          <statusCode>CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY</statusCode>
        </errors>
        <id>01I28000001HT0sEAG</id>
        <success>false</success>
      </result>
      <result>
        <errors>
          <message>Entity type is not undeletable</message>
          <statusCode>CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY</statusCode>
        </errors>
        <id>01I28000001aDreEAE</id>
        <success>false</success>
      </result>
    </undeleteResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the documented [CRUD-Based Calls](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_crud_based_calls_intro.htm) for the Metadata API. No <s>joy</s> undelete.

> Use the following CRUD-based calls to work with metadata components in a manner similar to how synchronous API calls in the enterprise WSDL act upon objects.
>
> - `createMetadata()`
>     Adds one or more new metadata components to your organization synchronously.readMetadata()
>     Returns one or more metadata components from your organization synchronously.
> - `updateMetadata()`
>     Updates one or more metadata components in your organization synchronously.upsertMetadata()
>     Creates or updates one or more metadata components in your organization synchronously.
> - `deleteMetadata()`
>     Deletes one or more metadata components from your organization synchronously.renameMetadata()
>     Renames a metadata component in your organization synchronously.
> - `create()`
>     Deprecated. Adds one or more new metadata components to your organization asynchronously. This call is removed as of API version 31.0 and is available in earlier versions only. Use createMetadata()instead.
> - `delete()`
>     Deprecated. Deletes one or more components from your organization asynchronously. This call is removed as of API version 31.0 and is available in earlier versions only. Use deleteMetadata()instead.
> - `update()`
>     Deprecated. Updates one or more components in your organization asynchronously. This call is removed as of API version 31.0 and is available in earlier versions only. Use updateMetadata() orrenameMetadata() instead.